# How do I create character arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, numpy

Say I have the following array:

```
import numpy as np
a = ['hello','snake','plate']
```

I want this to turn into a numpy array `b` so that:

```
b[0,0] = 'h'
b[0,1] = 'e'
b[0,2] = 'l'
b[1,0] = 's'
...
```

I want the standard numpy tricks to work, like broadcasting, comparison, etc.

How is it done?  And where is this in the numpy documentation?

Thanks!

Uri

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a numpy character array directly e.g.:

```
b = np.array([ ['h','e','l','l','o'],['s','n','a','k','e'],['p','l','a','t','e'] ])
```

The usual array tricks work with this.

If you have `a` and wish to *generate* b from it, note that:

```
list('hello') == ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

So you can do something like:

```
b = np.array([ list(word) for word in a ])
```

However, if `a` has words of unequal length (e.g. `['snakes','on','a','plane']`), what do you want to do with the shorter words? You could pad them with spaces to the longest word:

```
wid = max(len(w) for w in a)
b = np.array([ list(w.center(wid)) for w in a])
```

Which the `string.center(width)` pads with spaces, centering the string. You could also use `rjust` or `ljust` (see [string docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)).

Comment: Thanks, this will probably work for me.  But I wonder if there is a way where I don't have to use the list comprehension?  I am going to have to perform this operation many many times (with larger arrays to boot).  Is there a single numpy command that will do it with the loops in compiled code?

Comment: I don't know of any numpy command that specifically splits strings into individual letters whilst coercing to a matrix. I think you may be stuck with list comprehensions (but we'll see, maybe someone knows a magic function that does this).

Answer (score 23):

Actually, you can do this without any copies or list comprehensions in numpy (caveats about non-equal-length strings aside...). Just view it as a 1 character string array and reshape it:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(['hello','snake','plate'], dtype=str)
y = x.view('S1').reshape((x.size, -1))

print repr(y)
```

This yields:

```
array([['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'],
       ['s', 'n', 'a', 'k', 'e'],
       ['p', 'l', 'a', 't', 'e']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Generally speaking, though, I'd avoid using numpy arrays to store strings in most cases.  There are cases where it's useful, but you're usually better off sticking to data structures that allow variable-length strings for, well, holding strings.

Comment: for python3 you need to write dtype=bytes if the string is an ascii string

Comment: If you want Unicode strings to work, change dtype=np.unicode_  and view('U1')

Comment: What is the reverse operation to turn it back again for that?

Answer (score 3):

Specify the string length as the shape parameter with unicode 1 char

```
> string_array = ['..##.#..#.', '##..#.....', '#...##..#.', '####.#...#', '##.##.###.', '##...#.###', '.#.#.#..##', '..#....#..', '###...#.#.', '..###..###']
> numpy.array(string_array,dtype=('U1',10))
array([['.', '.', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '#', '.'],
       ['#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '.'],
       ['#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#'],
       ['#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.'],
       ['#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#'],
       ['.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#'],
       ['.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.'],
       ['#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#']], dtype='<U1')
```

This apparently should never have worked - https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18407 and stops working in numpy 1.20.1 but an easy replacement is

```
numpy.array(list(map(list, string_array)))
```

which converts the string list to a list of char lists before numpy receives it avoiding the need to explicitly set the dtype.

Comment: I recognize this input! It's the first tile in the sample data from [Advent of Code 2020 Day 20](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/20).