# python - formatting a string with key value pair separate by ':'

Tags: python, formatting

I am building a string of following pattern

```
"Key1":"Value1"
"Key1232131":"Value2"
"Key12321":"Value3"
```

I want to format it like

```
"Key1"          :   "Value1"
"Key1232131"    :   "Value2"
"Key12321"      :   "Value3"
```

I tried to insert them in a dictionary and pretty print it but that doesn't do it. I think I might need a table like representation. What can I use in python/in general to achieve this?

Comment: Hi - can you show us the code you've tried (even if it isn't working)? (edit your question and add it there, don't reply in comments because code formatting here is awful)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> key="Key1" 
>>> value = "Value1"
>>> '{!r:<10}:{!r:>10}'.format(key, value)
"'Key1'    :  'Value1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a matrix is one solution:

```
matrix = [['Key1 :', 'Value1'], ['Key1232131 :', 'Value2'], ['Key12321 :', 'Value3']]
for row in matrix:
   print ' '.join(row)
```

[How to make matrices in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084476/how-to-make-matrices-in-python) shows how to make a matrix in general