# Python 2.7 creating a matrix from lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I have two lists:

`a_list` contains distinct tupled ids:

`a_list = [('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4')...etc]`

and lists within lists of tuples called `check_list`:

`check_list = [[[('1'), ('2')]], [[('2'), ('3')], [('3'),('4')]], [[('1'),('3')]]...etc]`

I've got a problem that is a little too complex for my python skill level...  I'm attempting to form a matrix to be outputted to a csv file, with the following structure:

```
     1 2 3 4
```

`1    1 1 0 0`

`2    0 1 2 1`

`3    1 0 1 0`

Where each value is the count of the number from `a_list` in `check_list`.

I've looked at numpy and I have no knowledge.  I've played around with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19084476/how-to-make-matrices-in-python) but I cant seem to get a full understanding to transfer it to my problem.  I'm pretty limited with array knowledge, too.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually have tuples  in your sublists because as posted the parens are doing nothing?

Comment: Do you want to tell us anything with the parenthesis around the strings? Are these actually supposed to be tuples? What's the problem, counting or writing to a file?

Comment: yes, the parenthesis are supposed to be tuples and are supposed to be there.  The problem is the counting.

Comment: Then edit your question. As it stands, `a_list` is just a list of strings because `('1') == '1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the counts using a Counter dict, sort by key to get the counts in Order using an OrderedDict to maintain that order and use `dict.viewkeys` to find what keys are missing.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
from itertools import chain

check_list = [[[('1',), ('2',)]], [[('2',), ('3',)], [('3',), ('4',)]], [[('1',), ('3',)]]]

a_list = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]

cn = OrderedDict(sorted(Counter(a_list).items()))

print(" ".join([str(t[0]) for t in cn]))
for chk in check_list:
    _cn = Counter(chain(*chk))
    # cn.keys() python 3
    diff = cn.viewkeys() - _cn
    for k  in cn:
        if k not in diff:
            print(_cn[k], end=" ")
        else:
            print(0, end=" ")
    print()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
1 1 0 0 
0 1 2 1 
1 0 1 0
```

If you don't care about the order you can remove the sorted/Ordereddict logic:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

check_list = [[[('1',), ('2',)]], [[('2',), ('3',)], [('3',), ('4',)]], [[('1',), ('3',)]]]

a_list = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]

cn = Counter(a_list)

print(" ".join([str(t[0]) for t in cn]))
for chk in check_list:
    _cn = Counter(chain(*chk))
    diff = cn.viewkeys() - _cn
    for k  in cn:
        if k not in diff:
            print(_cn[k], end=" ")
        else:
            print(0, end=" ")
    print()
```

That will give you an arbitrary order:

```
3 4 1 2
0 0 1 1 
2 1 0 1 
1 0 1 0
```

To write to a csv:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
from itertools import chain
from csv import writer

check_list = [[[('1',), ('2',)]], [[('2',), ('3',)], [('3',), ('4',)]], [[('1',), ('3',)]]]

a_list = [('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',)]

with open("out.csv","w") as out:
    wr = writer(out,delimiter=" ")
    cn = OrderedDict(sorted(Counter(a_list).items()))
    wr.writerow(list(chain(*cn)))
    for chk in check_list:
        _cn = Counter(chain(*chk))
        diff = cn.viewkeys() - _cn
        wr.writerow([_cn[k] if k not in diff else 0 for k in cn])
```

out.csv:

```
1 2 3 4
1 1 0 0
0 1 2 1
1 0 1 0
```

Comment: Perfect!  And I understand it too!