# Python best way to remove char from string by index

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, substring

I'm removing an char from string like this:

```
S = "abcd"
Index=1 #index of string to remove
ListS = list(S)
ListS.pop(Index)
S = "".join(ListS)
print S
#"acd"
```

I'm sure that this is **not** the best way to do it.

**EDIT**
I didn't mentioned that I need to manipulate a string size with length ~ 10^7. 
So it's important to care about efficiency.

> Can someone help me.  Which pythonic way to do it?

Comment: @soon please mind the question. It's not duplicate.

Comment: It is duplicate, please take a look at the first answer of the linked question.

Comment: It's very duplicate. All the answers are pretty much duplicate too (including my own).

Comment: Voting for reopen since the OP wants a workable solution for a sequence of ~10^7 elements - the question marked as duplicate is for "ordinary" string sizes.

Comment: @alvaro - please reword your question to include your expected strign size. (or ask another question altogether)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can bypass all the list operations with slicing:

```
S = S[:1] + S[2:]
```

or more generally

```
S = S[:Index] + S[Index + 1:]
```

Many answers to your question (including ones like this) can be found here: [How to delete a character from a string using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559559/2988730). However, that question is nominally about deleting by value, not by index.

Comment: That's the most efficient way? Seems so not pythonic. It's works like I wanted.

Comment: Why do you care about most efficient way? What is the size of the string and how often do you remove a character from it?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao. There is no "efficient" way to remove elements from a string. A string in Python is immutable. This means that you are going to have to create temporary containers and a new final string regardless. If you want efficient, you can do something like extend `list` and implement a custom `__str__` method.

Comment: String size 10^7. The problem is about finding palindromes and remove char til the string becomes a palindrome  So I guess I need to care about efficient.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao then keep a list of characters instead of a string, a list is mutable and doesn't require creating copies to change.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao. Consider using a `numpy` array for something that size. If you care about efficient, you should not be using pure Python in the first place.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the tips!! It helped me a lot.

Comment: Here is something you may want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9476797/2988730. Note that while the storage for arrays is immutable, you are free to shift elements left or use a mask. For 10^7 I would probably do the latter.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen yep!! Great suggestion. I will follow this tip to solve this problem! Thanks !

Comment: Every time you modify the list size, you are calling `realloc` under the hood. Be careful about how you use lists too.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao, Not sure if holding string in a list or array will be enough to solve the problem. 10^7 is too long for brute-force solution. This depends on the full problem statement, though.

Answer (score 7):

Slicing is the best and easiest approach I can think of, here are some other alternatives:

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> def remove(s, indx):
        return ''.join(x for x in s if s.index(x) != indx)

>>> remove(s, 1)
'acd'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def remove(s, indx):
        return ''.join(filter(lambda x: s.index(x) != 1, s))

>>> remove(s, 1)
'acd'
```

Remember that indexing is zero-based.

Comment: This does not work as expected if the string has repeated characters. For instance, `OOOXX` will return `XX` after calling method `remove`. And the OP mentioned the need to process a string with millions of characters, so it is impossible that there are not repeated chars.

Answer (score 6):

You can replace the Index character with "".

```
str = "ab1cd1ef"
Index = 3
print(str.replace(str[Index],"",1))
```

Comment: This will not work as expected for `Index = 2` since it will also remove the value at `5`.

Comment: If add 1 in replace ? Limit the replace to one occurrence. @MadPhysicist

Comment: Modified my answer and now Index = 2 will be taken care, Please upvote..thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are absolutely right. Got you point just now.

Answer (score 2):

```
def missing_char(str, n):

  n = abs(n)
  front = str[:n]   # up to but not including n
  back = str[n+1:]  # n+1 through end of string
  return front + back
```

Answer (score 0):

```
S = "abcd"
Index=1 #index of string to remove
S = S.replace(S[Index], "")
print(S)
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: What if, `S = "zzzz"`, I am getting `empty` but it should return `zzz`

Comment: @0Knowledge `S.replace(S[index], "", 1)`