# Remove items inbetween 2 indexes Python

Tags: python-3.x

How could I remove all items in between 2 indexes in a list/tuple?
e.g `'abcdefghijklmnop'` with `begin = 4` and `end = 7` should result in `'abcdhijklmnop'` (`'efg'` removed)

Comment: do `begin` and `end` refer to indices or the actual characters in the string?

Comment: They refer to indices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python best way to remove char from string by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066836/python-best-way-to-remove-char-from-string-by-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list slicing:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
b = a[:3] + a[7:]
print(b)
```

The result is `[1, 2, 3, 8]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ip = '123456789'
begin = 3
end = 6
res = ip[:begin]+ip[end:]
```

output:

```
123789
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list slicing as below:

```
li = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p']
del li[4:7]
print(li)
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
```

As in the post, you've provided it as a string, so in that case you can use string slicing:

```
s= 'abcdefghijklmnop'
start = 4
end = 7
s= s[0: start:] + s[end::]
print(s)
```

output:

```
abcdhijklmnop
```