# Slicing the second last character

Tags: python, slice

I have this string here `'[2,3,1,1,]'`

Im new to slicing and I only know how to slice from the start and from the end but not somewhere between, not even sure if that is possible.

could someone tell me how I can slice this `'[2,3,1,1,]'` to this `'[2,3,1,1]'`
So removing the second last character only.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066836/python-best-way-to-remove-char-from-string-by-index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to delete the second last character, your can do like this,

```
s = "[2,3,1,1,]"

s[:-2] + s[-1]
# '[2,3,1,1]'
```

`s[:-2]` -> Will slice the string from 0 to -2 index location (without -2 index)

`s[-1]` -> Will fetch the last element

`s[:-2] + s[-1]` -> concatenation of the strigs

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining what you're doing.

Comment: @Chris Make sense, updated it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you have that string, slice *both* characters and add the `]` back on!

```py
source_string = "[2,3,1,1,]"
if source_string.endswith(",]"):
    source_string = source_string[:-2] + "]"
```

However, often lists stored as strings are not very useful - you may really want to convert the whole thing to a collection of numbers (perhaps manually removing the `"[]"` and splitting by `,`, or using [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)), potentially converting it *back* to a string to display later

```py
>>> source_string = "[2,3,1,1,]"
>>> import ast
>>> my_list = ast.literal_eval(source_string)
>>> my_list
[2, 3, 1, 1]
>>> str(my_list)
'[2, 3, 1, 1]'
```

Comment: Thank you, did not know that endswith() even existed.

Comment: Note that this changes the spacing. maybe `f"[{','.join(map(str, my_list))}]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for this one case

```
txt = "[2,3,1,1,]"
print(f"{txt[:-2]}{txt[-1]}")
```

Even tho storing lists as string is a bit weird

> txt[:-2] will get the characters from 0 index to -2 index

> txt[-1] will get the last character which is "]"

> then I concatenate both with an f"" string

You can use this if you don't wanna use an f string

```
print(txt[:-2], txt[-1], sep="")
```

the "sep" argument is so there won't be space between the two prints

Answer (score 0):

Using built-in functions such as `str.rstrip`

```
l = '[2,3,1,1,]'

l_new = f"{l.rstrip('],')}]" # it doesn't matter the order!
print(l_new)
```

or `str.rpartition`

```
a, _, b = l.rpartition(',')
l_new = a + b
print(l_new)
```

you can avoid an explicit slicing. See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) for details.

The 1st approach is *universal*, hence doesn't produce any side-effects. The 2nd may give rise to side-effects if the final last character is not a `,`. If necessary use a check, i.e. `str.endswith`, to fix it.